# react-responsive-modal, modal is flickering badly when opened

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, flicker

On click of a link, a modal opens up. But the modal is flickering badly. Not sure why it is flickering, is it because of any wrong property or any other factor. This happens in chrome only, Other browsers does not show this kind of issue.How can i fix the flickering of my modal?

Comment: What have you done to debug? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example that reproduces the issue. It may help to see if you can reproduce it in a codesandbox running in Chrome that you can also share here.

Comment: This problem is occurring randomly. I created a sample poc to attach which did not show this behaviour. Modal works as expected.Is there is generic thing about modal that should be taken care ?

Comment: Well, I guess first we should figure out what "flickering" means. Reason could be almost any number of things though. You say it is only acting odd in chrome though, so doing weird state updates likely isn't the culprit. Without a solid repro or code to look at it's hard to provide any more assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Just incase anyone else has the same issue. In my case it was caused by the modal animation, I fixed it by applying `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` on both the modal and overlay and the flickering stopped

Comment: Awesome! Had to add ``!important`` coz of specificity issues.

Comment: Turns out I had implemented my own show and fade classes in a global CSS file.  changed them to myFade and myShow, and the flicker stopped.